# Metal Shading Language Texture Will Not Clear

Tags: graphics, metal

In my scene I have 2 objects, a Water Well and a Quad.  The Well has 2 textures, a baseColorTexture (index 0) and a normalMapTexture (index 1).  The quad has no textures applied to it.  When Rendering the scene I get something that looks like this.
[image]
THE QUAD IS USING THE WELLS IMAGE.  Now when looking at the debugger I find that there is no image bound to either index 0 or 1 for the quad like the picture shows below.
[image]

My Shaders use the following when using a texture. `if(!is_null_texture(texture) { ... }`

Can anyone please give me an idea as to what may be occuring?

You can see all the code here:
github.com/twohyjr/Metal-Game-Engine-Tutorial/blob/master/….

but it looks like this.
`float4 color = material.color;  if(!is_null_texture(baseColorMap)) {  color = baseColorMap.sample(sampler2d, texCoord);  }`

Comment: What does the fragment shader return when the texture is null? In other words, is there an `else` clause for that `if` you mentioned? Or what code follows the `if`? Probably best to show the whole shader.

Comment: @KenThomases You can see all the code here: https://github.com/twohyjr/Metal-Game-Engine-Tutorial/blob/master/Full%20Current%20Project/Game%20Engine/Graphics/shaders/BasicShaders.metal. but it looks like this.

   float4 color = material.color;
    if(!is_null_texture(baseColorMap)) {
        color = baseColorMap.sample(sampler2d, texCoord);
    }